# Keep the ID variable when creating seqelist in TraMineR

Tags: r, sequence, traminer

I am creating a list of sequences with TraMineR with the following code:

```
cj.seqe <- seqecreate(id=cj$party_id, time=cj$DATE_IN_num, event=cj$EVT_CD)
```

However, this list only contains the events and drops the id variable. I would like to merge the event sequences back to the original data. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with the following:

`cj.seqe <- seqecreate(data=cj, id="party_id", time=cj$DATE_IN_num, event=cj$EVT_CD)`

I suggest this because, to my experience, when I tried defining the id in **seqcreate** function in this way
`id=dataset.name$variable_id`  didn't work!

Whereas trying defining id with `id="variabile_id"` worked!

I hope this could help despite I have no rigorous explanation.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue